# Does forge enable you to test your revert messages?

Tags: solidity, foundry, forge, revert

I'm currently using the expectRevert construction and then just printing things out to see the msg, but is there a way to test this via an assertion? perhaps expectRevertWithMessage or something of the like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Forge does enable you to test your revert messages. It allows you to preview what your messages will look like once they are sent and enables you to make any changes before sending them.